# MongoDB update query - document with embeded query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update values in documents which pass some criteria. In my case the array "Orders" contains few objects, each object contain specific object "PendingDetails", right here is a string field "State" which I would like to modify.

The criteria are: username: "Pablo.Lobo@gmail.com"; PendingDetails.State: "not null", "exists"

[Document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbvYZ.jpg)

```
db.getCollection('users').updateMany(
   {
     "Username" : "Pablo.Lobo@gmail.com",
     "Orders": { $elemMatch: { "PendingDetails.State": { $exists: true, $ne: null } } } 
   },
   { $set: { "Orders.$.PendingDetails.State" : "123" } }
)
```

Expected result is that every object in Order in section PendingDetails.State will have "123" at least if it existed and were not null

The issue is that values are not changing

Comment: So whats the issue? The values are not changing?

Comment: Yes, the values are not changing. Once I made a change but only for one object as you can see in that case array "orders" got 3 objects [0];[1];[2] so my solution just partialy works.